# Swift changing my xcdatamodeld and XXX.swift is not created only XXX+CoreDataProperties.swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, nsmanagedobject

I was wondering if this is know issue in XCode 7 beta. In my case I had to add an attribute to an entity. After addding the attribute I
- deleted XXXX.swift
- deleted XXXX+CoreDataProperties.swift
- selected Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass
- realised only XXXX+CoreDataProperties.swift was created (did not see XXXX.swift)
- created a new class file XXXX.swift, but on save a message displayed overwrite existing one (so apparently XXXX.swift is still there) so i did.
- after creating the XXXX file I just put this code

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class XXXX: NSManagedObject {

}
```

- but to my suprise the newly created XXXX.swift isn't displayed + the top UI bar of XCode disappeared
- after restarting XCode i the top UI bar appeared + newly created XXXX.swift displays

Answer (score 2):

When using Swift, the CoreData model will only auto-create the `+CoreDataProperties.swift` file when updating a model entity.  This is by design, as we should now put our custom class extensions in the `MyEntity.swift` file so that they don't get overwritten.  When you edit your model, don't delete your `MyEntity.swift` file.  That one is not managed automatically by Xcode, only the `MyEntity+CoreDataProperties.swift` file is, and it's the only one that will be re-generated for you.